# Internet Explorer 8 is not refreshing after html is changed via javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, layout, internet-explorer-8

I am updating the content of a page's section using AJAX. The issue I'm having is with IE 8: the browser doesn't update the footer position if the section that is being replaced is larger or smaller than before. I've used Chrome, Firefox and IE 9 and it works fine, but in IE8 it doesn't work.

What's weird? If I select some text on the page, the footer goes to the right position... Or if I modify the style of the footer with IE8 developer tools (i.e. disabling and enabling a style) it also works.

I'm using jQuery function `$(element).replaceWith(...)`, but I've also tried using `$(element).empty(); $(element).html(...)` with the same results.

You can check the bug here (with IE), clicking on the "Ver más" button at the bottom of the page: http://bit.ly/RbAxyf

Thanks in advance

Update: Some people had the same problem, they solve it doing the hack I mentioned: adding and removing a style. [Dynamic Elements are not appearing in IE8 until there is a mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350441/dynamic-elements-are-not-appearing-in-ie8-until-there-is-a-mouse-click) (it didn't work for me doing it programatically)

Comment: Works fine on mine. The footer needs to be pushed down, but it works.

Comment: The content is added, the problem is the footer is not moved (only IE8).

Comment: The wrapping element probably has a fixed height - remove it.