# Dojo Xhr: Result Content is Not Appearing until there is a mouse click anywhere on page

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, dojo, offline-caching, html5-appcache

i'm building an offline application with Dojo 1.7, using Dojo RDD, generating forms dynamically and storing them in cache.
now every time when i fetch something through ajax i have to remove dojo registry because dojo binds widgets by id if i dont clear registry it will cause problem in parsing dojo widgets because their ids already exist in widget registry, but when i clear registry every time it causes another problem. everything works fine but the result content only appear when clicking anywhere on page. same as described in:

[Dynamic Elements are not appearing in IE8 until there is a mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350441/dynamic-elements-are-not-appearing-in-ie8-until-there-is-a-mouse-click)

but, in this case this problem is with Chrome.

and the solution provided in above url doesn't work in this case.

exp:

//in some cases registry is destructor is not called.

dojo.xhrGet({

```
        url: serverUrl,
        content: {},
        load: function(result) {

            //destroying widget registry.(before any parsing)
            dijit.registry._destroyAll();

            // here is html processing.
        },

        error: function(error) {
            utility.handleException(error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide some related code so that we can help debug your problem.

Comment: but in some cases i just destroy only the widgets that are conflicting. the form contains like 150 fields so that alot to handle manually, most of the time is just call destructor.